# Unable to record audio with audio package in R studio

Tags: r, windows, audio, rstudio

I am unable to record audio in `windows 10` with `audio` package. I can play sin thing but unable to record.

```
play(sin(1:100000/20))
```

Above thing works

```
x <- rep(NA_real_, 16000)
# start recording into x
record(x, 8000, 1)
```

Nothing happens.

When i tried to run:

```
.Call(audio_recorder, x, as.double(8000), as.integer(1),PACKAGE = "audio")
```

> object audio_recorder not found

Comment: You did not assign `audio_recorder` object

Comment: Could you help me how to do that ??

Comment: You have to store something in `audio_recorder`, probably `record(x, 8000, 1)`. Please follow https://rforge.net/audio/

Comment: I did as mentioned in the code still it does not work